# Python Pandas: referencing variables from different loop levels when appending to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a dataframe df with the following columns: ['doc_id','asent']

'asent' is a series of sentences e.g. ['hello','what is your name?','goodbye'] that I'm running a sentiment analysis on and saving to a separate dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['doc_id','sentence','vs'])

for para in df['asent']:
    for sentence in para:
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
        df2 = df2.append(vs, ignore_index = True)
```

What I can't figure out is how to add sentence and doc_id to the vs results when appending.

I've tried using df['doc_id'], vs in the append and get "append() got multiple values for argument 'ignore_index'"

I've tried concatenating ds['doc_id'] to vs as a new variable before appending that and get 'first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"'.

Added: I figured out how to add sentence to the output. Since vs is a dictionary and to add sentence I used:

```
    vs['sentence'] = sentence
```

But adding doc_id is still a mystery.

ADDED: Got it by using a counter to track where in the dataframe I'm at. Clunky but it works:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['doc_id','sentence','vs'])
x = -1
for para in df['asent']:
    x += 1
    for sentence in para:
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
        vs['doc_id'] = df.doc_id[x]
        df2 = df2.append(vs, ignore_index = True)
```

(I started the counter at -1 since the first row is at [0])

Thank you-all for the help!

Comment: Is `vs` a DataFrame? You can check it by running `type(vs)`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like vs is an empty column that you fill with a function

so you shoudnt iterarte at all,
just do:

```
df2.vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(df.asent)
```

or the apply method:

```
df2.vs = df.asent.apply(analyzer.polarity_scores)
```

you can go either way..

Comment: That gives the error: 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split''. df.asent is a series within the dataframe, hence the for loops...

Comment: there might be a problem in your method, you can use the apply method
df2.vs = df.asent.apply(analyzer.polarity_scores)
make sure there is no () in the function , its not a calll.
this will pass df.asent every row.